# importing mysql file into access DB

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

i need to import a mysql file into my access db. how do i do this?

here's a sample of the mysql file:

```
*
MySQL Data Transfer
Source Host: 10.0.0.5
Source Database: jnetdata
Target Host: 10.0.0.5
Target Database: jnetdata
Date: 5/26/2009 12:27:33 PM
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for chavrusas
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `chavrusas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_created` datetime default NULL,
  `luser_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `ruser_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `luser_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ruser_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `SessionDay` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `SessionTime` datetime default NULL,
  `WeeklyReminder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `reminder_phone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `calling_card` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `notes` mediumtext,
  `ended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `end_date` datetime default NULL,
  `initiated_by_student` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `initiated_by_volunteer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

directly from that file won't be easy. i suggest instead installing mysql and myodbc. once you have the database loaded in mysql, you can connect to the database in access using an ODBC linked table. from their you can either access the data directly and just use access as a front-end to the database, or you can create tables and copy the rows in to access.